# Pythonの print 関数を使用してログ書き込みを行うアプリケーションが、Amazon ECS+FargateでCloudWatchLogsに即時書き込まれない

Tags: python, aws, docker, logging, aws-cloudwatch

### 質問内容

- `print`関数を使用して標準出力に書き出されたログが、ECSタスクが実行終了されるまで書き込まれない（ログストリームが作成されない）原因は何だと考えられますか？

  - 後述の検証にて、`logging.StreamHandler`を使用したログ書き出しではログが即時書き込まれることを確認しています。

### アプリケーションと基盤設定の概要

Amazon ECS + Fargateの構成で、Pythonのアプリケーションを実行しています。
ECSタスクのログドライバーに`awslogs`を設定しており、CloudWatchLogsにログを書き込むように設定しています。
コンテナ内で実行されるPythonコードは、`print`関数を使用して、ログ出力を行っています。

### 発生した事象

ECSタスクを実行すると、出力先のロググループにログストリームが作成されません。
ECSタスクの実行が完了されたタイミングで、ログストリームが作成され、ログが保存されました。

### 仮説

`print`関数を使用してログを書き出しているアプリケーションの他に、`logging`モジュールのロガーを使用してログを書き出しているアプリケーションも存在しており、こちらについては即時ログストリームが作成され、ログが保管されます。
ロガーには、`logging.StreamHandler`インスタンスを渡しています。

```py
import time
from logging import INFO, Formatter, StreamHandler, getLogger

logger = getLogger()
logger.setLevel(INFO)

if not logger.hasHandlers():
    handler = StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    formatter = Formatter(
        '[%(levelname)s]\t%(asctime)s\t%(message)s\n',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )

    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.info('開始')
```

`print`関数と`logging.StreamHandler`で書き込む際の動きが違う可能性があると思っています。

### 検証したこと

以下の2つの Pythonコードを、ECS+Fargateの構成にデプロイし、タスクを実行してみました。
なお、両タスクで使用しているDockerfileは共通のものです。

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY main.py main.py

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

#### 1.`print`関数を使用したログ書き出し

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime


def log(log: str):
    print(f'{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S} {log}')


log('開始')

for _ in range(20):
    time.sleep(10)
    log('tick')

log('終了')
```

#### 2.`logging.StreamHandler`を使用したログ書き出し

```py
import time
from logging import INFO, Formatter, StreamHandler, getLogger

logger = getLogger()
logger.setLevel(INFO)

if not logger.hasHandlers():
    handler = StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    formatter = Formatter(
        '[%(levelname)s]\t%(asctime)s\t%(message)s\n',
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )

    for handler in logger.handlers:
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.info('開始')

for _ in range(20):
    time.sleep(10)
    logger.info('tick')

logger.info('終了')
```

#### 検証結果

#### 1.`print`関数を使用したログ書き出し

ECSタスクの実行が完了したらログストリームが作成され、ログが保管される

#### 2.`logging.StreamHandler`を使用したログ書き出し

ECSタスクの実行中にログストリームが作成され、ログが保管される

#### 環境情報

- python: 3.9
- Fargate プラットフォームバージョン: 1.4.0
- ECSタスクオペレーティングシステム/アーキテクチャ: LINUX/-

#### 2024/01/18 追記

追加で2点検証しました。

結論：両方とも、ECSタスクの実行中にログストリームが作成され、ログが保管される

##### 1.1 `print`関数の引数に、`flush=True`を追加

```py
print('hello', flush=True)
```

##### 1.2 `print`関数の引数に、`file=sys.stderr`を追加

```py
print("hello", file=sys.stderr)
```

@oriri san
@jackson san
コメントいただきありがとうございます。

### 結論

検証結果から、以下の結論を得た。

- `print`関数のデフォルトの動作は、`sys.stdout`に出力されるようになっているが、標準出力はバッファリングを有しているため、バッファが開放されたタイミングでCloudWatchLogsに転送される。
- 一方、`sys.stderr`は、バッファリングされないため、CloudWatchLogsに即時転送される。
- `logging.StreamHandler`のデフォルトの出力先は`sys.stdeerr`のため、CloudWatchLogsに即時転送される。

Comment: `print('hello', flush=True)` のようにオプション付けるとどうなりますか？

Comment: `StreamHandler`のデフォルトの出力先は`stdout`ではなく`stderr`のようですが、`print("hoge", file=sys.stderr)`のようにするとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: @oriri 

コメントありがとうございます。
提案された内容で検証したところ、タスクの実行中にCloudWatchLogsにログが保管されました。
検証内容は質問本文に追記しました。

Comment: @jackson 

コメントありがとうございます。 提案された内容で検証したところ、タスクの実行中にCloudWatchLogsにログが保管されました。 検証内容は質問本文に追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(結論出てるようなので, 補足的な？)

---

stdin, stdout, stderr (標準入力・標準出力・標準エラー出力)は OSが用意します
(UNIX系 OSの仕組みで, 例えば[汎用機](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0)用 OSには存在しません。UNIX系以外でも 機能取り込んでる例はあります)

stdout, stderr の用途の違いは

- stdout: 比較的 速度が重視されるため, 通常はバッファリング(蓄積)が行われる
- stderr: 主にエラーメッセージの表示に利用され, 通常 (ただちに表示されたほうがよいので)バッファリングされない

例えばプログレスバーを使うとき, 以下のコードでは期待した動きにはなりません
(Python含めそれ以外のプログラミング言語でも同様)

```py
for _ in 処理のリスト:
    print('*', end='')
    何らかの処理
```

- 出力毎に フラッシュを行う
- `setbuf` などの APIでバッファリングを(一時的に)制御
- (上記の場合)専用のプログレスバー・パッケージを利用する。(この質問での場合 `logging.StreamHandler`など)

などの対処を行うことになるでしょう

質問にある "auto flush" は, 「`setbuf` などの API」を指すのでしょう
Linuxコンテナー利用するのなら以下にマニュアルがあります

- [setbuf(3) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html)
- [setbuf, setbuffer, setlinebuf, setvbuf - ストリームのバッファーリングの操作](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/ja/man3/setbuf.3.html)
- (どこが出してるマニュアルか分からないが) [setvbuf(3) ストリームのバッファリングの操作](https://ja.manpages.org/setvbuf/3)